# How to call Method(Function) from one webpage to another webpage using Master page in ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have created a master page `Login_Nav` and created two pages `AuthenticationMethods.aspx` and `password.aspx` with masterpage `Login_Nav.master`.

I have also created a method `CheckAuth()` in `AuthenticationMethods.aspx` page and I want to call that method into `password.aspx` page for that I have created the instance

```
Model_AuthenticationMethods authenticationMethods = new Model_AuthenticationMethods();
```

and it is throwing an error

> Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference

I'm not sure how to call that method `CheckAuth()` where I want, below is my code

`Login_Nav` master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login_Nav.master.cs" Inherits="Login_Nav" %>
public partial class Login_Nav : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

`AuthenticationMethods aspx` page with master page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Login_Nav.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AuthenticationMethods.aspx.cs" Inherits="Model_AuthenticationMethods" %>
public partial class Model_AuthenticationMethods : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public void CheckAuth()
    {
        // my logic will go here
    }
}
```

`password.aspx` page with master page - I want to call the `CheckAuth();` method in `password.aspx` page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Login_Nav.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="password.aspx.cs" Inherits="password" %>
public partial class Model_Data : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Creating an instance of Model_AuthenticationMethods
        Model_AuthenticationMethods authenticationMethods = new Model_AuthenticationMethods(); //getting error "are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference"

        authenticationMethods.CheckAuth()

        // CheckAuth();
    }
}
```

Please suggest how to call that method `{creating an instance or using inheritance concept}`

I don't have a good knowledge to achieve this concept